# What is PostgreSQL equivalent for MSSQL STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] ) function?

Tags: postgresql

In MSSQL STR returns character data converted from numeric data. The character data is right-justified, with a specified length and decimal precision. SELECT STR(123.45, 6, 1) return ' 123.5' (not '123.5') in MSSQL. Also, SELECT STR(123.45, 2, 2) return '**' in MSSQL.

Comment: `to_char()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct corresponding Postgres function. You have a couple things going on: rounding at variable length, padding the result and result length validation. But easy enough to create your own SQL function: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aef4265e3f1cbc46f6e2e01241a7fa63))

```
create or replace 
 function str(value_in   numeric   
             ,length_in  integer default 7
             ,dec_len_in integer default 2
             ) 
   returns text  
  language sql 
as $$ 
   select case when length(val) > length_in 
               then rpad('*',length_in,'*')     -- or just '**' 
               else lpad(val,length_in,'#')     -- for demo using #, for real use ' '
          end
     from (select round(value_in, dec_len_in )::text) sq(val)
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more correct answer

```
create or replace function str(
    _float_expression decimal,
    _length integer default 10,
    _decimal integer default 0
)
    returns text
    language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
    _res text;
begin

    -- analog STR() function in ms sql

  
    if _length = 0 then
        return null;
    end if;

    if _decimal > 16 then
        _decimal := 16;
    end if;


    _res := (select case
                        when length(floor(_float_expression)::text) > _length then rpad('*', _length, '*')
                        else case
                                 when right(left(val, _length), 1) = '.' then
                                     lpad(left(val, _length - 1), _length, ' ')
                                 else
                                     lpad(left(val, _length), _length, ' ')
                            end
                        end
             from (select round(_float_expression, _decimal)::text as val) as res);

    return _res;
end
$$
```